# Como gerar uma matriz 2d com uma das posições escolhida aletoriamente tendo um valor diferente?

Tags: javascript, algoritmo

Quero gerar uma matriz 10x10, onde todos os elementos serão "B", exceto uma das posições, que deverá ser escolhida aleatoriamente e ter o valor "8".

```js
var m = [];

for(i=0; i < 10; i++){
  
  m[i] = [];
}
document.write("<table>");

for(i=0; i < 10; i++){

  document.write("<tr>");
  
  for(j=0; j<10;j++){
    //
    m[i][j]=["B"];

    document.write("<td>" + m[i][j] +"</td>");
  }
  document.write("</tr>")
}

document.write("</table>");
```

Comment: Reverti a edição porque ela descaracterizava a pergunta (basicamente ela deixava de ser uma pergunta de fato, o que invalidava a resposta). Se quer deixar sua própria solução, basta usar o campo de resposta abaixo

Comment: na verdade so queria agradecer, ai tentei apagar o textão

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você quer que todas as posições sejam "B", exceto uma delas (escolhida aleatoriamente), que deve ser "8", talvez nem precise criar a matriz. Basta gerar números aleatórios para a linha e coluna que devem ter o "8", e no próprio *loop* você verifica se está nesta linha e coluna:

```js
let tamanho = 10;
// escolhar linha e coluna aleatórias (entre zero e 9)
let linha = Math.floor(Math.random() * tamanho);
let coluna = Math.floor(Math.random() * tamanho);

document.write("<table>");
for (let i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
  document.write("<tr>");
  for (let j = 0; j < tamanho; j++) {
    if (i == linha && j == coluna) {
      // estou na linha e coluna escolhidas, imprime 8
      document.write("<td>8</td>");
    } else { // para todas as outras, imprime B
      document.write("<td>B</td>");
    }
  }
  document.write("</tr>")
}

document.write("</table>");
```

---

Mas se quiser guardar a matriz, bastar usar a mesma ideia para gerar os valores (e depois faça outro *loop* para imprimi-la):

```js
let tamanho = 10;
// escolhar linha e coluna aleatórias (entre zero e 9)
let linha = Math.floor(Math.random() * tamanho);
let coluna = Math.floor(Math.random() * tamanho);

let m = [];
for (let i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
  m[i] = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < tamanho; j++) {
    if (i == linha && j == coluna) {
      // estou na linha e coluna escolhidas, valor é 8
      m[i].push('8');
    } else { // para todas as outras, valor é B
      m[i].push('B');
    }
  }
}

document.write("<table>");
for (let i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
  document.write("<tr>");
  for (let j = 0; j < tamanho; j++) {
    document.write(`<td>${m[i][j]}</td>`);
  }
  document.write("</tr>")
}

document.write("</table>");
```

---

Outra opção é usar [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) para preencher os arrays. Como na verdade a "matriz" é um array de arrays (um array no qual cada elemento é outro array), podemos fazer assim:

```js
let tamanho = 10;
// criar array e preencher com outros arrays (por sua vez, preenchidos com "B")
let m = Array(tamanho).fill().map(() => Array(tamanho).fill('B'));

// escolhar linha e coluna aleatórias (entre zero e 9) e preencher com "8"
let linha = Math.floor(Math.random() * tamanho);
let coluna = Math.floor(Math.random() * tamanho);
m[linha][coluna] = '8';

document.write("<table>");
for (let i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
  document.write("<tr>");
  for (let j = 0; j < tamanho; j++) {
    document.write(`<td>${m[i][j]}</td>`);
  }
  document.write("</tr>")
}

document.write("</table>");
```

`Array(tamanho)` cria um array com o tamanho indicado. Depois preenchemos as posições de `m` com "nada" (a primeira chamada a `fill()`), para depois mapear cada valor para outro array preenchido com "B" (se você fizer apenas `Array(tamanho).fill(Array(tamanho).fill('B'))`, todas as posições serão preenchidas com o mesmo array, e ao mudar uma posição de um para "8", essa mudança se refletirá em todas as linhas; já usando [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) eu garanto que um novo array é gerado para cada linha).

Outra forma de criar o array é:

```
let m = Array.from(Array(tamanho), () => Array(tamanho).fill('B'));
```

A ideia é a mesma: eu crio um array com 10 posições, e cada elemento deste é mapeado para outro array com 10 posições preenchidas com "B".

Answer (score -1):

O que você pode fazer é por o `Math.random` para decidir se imprime "B" ou "8".

Neste exemplo eu estou testando se o número randômico é par mostra "B" senão "8":

```js
m[i][j]= Math.floor(Math.random()*100) % 10 % 2 == 0 ? "B" : '8';
```

Comment: Que bom que você gostou das respostas! Mas a melhor forma de agradecer a quem te ajudou é assinalando "aceite" na melhor resposta e votando em todas que te ajudaram. Assim você garante que quem escreveu a resposta receba algo em troca, além de tornar o site mais limpo e útil para todo mundo. Adicionar uma nova resposta assim (que não é uma resposta pra pergunta e deve ser removida) deixa o site mais confuso e pode atrapalhar.